# MySQL cannot connect

Tags: php, mysql, html, mobile

I am trying to create a mobile web app. I am using PHP for the login, but it won't work. The script name is checklogin.php

Here's my PHP code: http://pastebin.com/XchE0bMs

Here's my HTML code: http://pastebin.com/sCSCnRFX

Also when I login with my username and password it stops at checklogin.php and instead of a PHP error it says undefined.

==================================================================================
This is what the HTML page is supposed to look like, but instead it just says undefined. (That is a link):

[ipad.chriscosma.co.cc/problems.html](http://ipad.chriscosma.co.cc/problems.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type='password' name='password'/>
```

you forgot the name attribute.

Comment: And get rid off that session_register. It is a deprecated function and will be removed. Use session_start() and $_session. Plus, your code is vulnerable to sql injection. Use PDO or atleast use mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: i have added this and put the <form action="checklogin.php" method="POST"> in a different spot but i still cannot connect to the database.

Comment: I have gotten rid of session_register but it still can't connect

Comment: Check the hostname, username and password credentials. Your hosting provider should give you that. If it needs to create a user, create one and give proper credentials. You done it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow a user in mysql access to the database. You can do this in phpMyAdmin or the MySQL database wizard if you are using a cpanel

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you need to put all input field inside the  attributes.

So minimized :

```
<form action="checklogin.php" method="POST">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <label for="username">
                        Username
                    </label>
                    <input id="username" placeholder="" name="username" value="" type="text" />
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <label for="password">
                        Password
                    </label>
                    <input id="password" placeholder="" value="" type="password" />
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" data-theme="b" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="left" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Else it won't take those values. Aside from that the password needs the name='password' part.

Now does it says 'cannot connect' or 'cannot select DB' ?

Answer (score 0):

If you couldn't establish DB connection I suggest `die`-ing with `mysql_error`:

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$sqlusername", "$sqlpassword") or die("cannot connect: " . mysql_error());
```

This is only temporary and should be removed in production version but would give you an idea what might went wrong...